# Using a Nib file for a UIView -- Issue with layout

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am using Swift to create an application for administering quizzes, and for the "quiz" view, which contains all of the questions on separate "cards", I am having issues with the layout of the question card.

I am using a .xib file to create the outline for the card, and placed it in the storyboard file with a UIView. On the universal preview, it appears to be centered, but when I run the application on various devices, however, while the UIView is centered and appropriately sized based on the device that it is running on (it has a white background, so it is clearly visible), the nib that I designed extends past the margins set by the UIView.

How do I configure it so that the nib remains inside of the UIView that I placed on the storyboard? I have attached screenshots of the app running on an iPad and an iPhone 6, as well as the current constraints on the view, the original nib design, the size constraints on the original .xib file, and the universal view.

EDIT: StackOverflow won't let me post images, so I am linking to an imgur album with the screenshots. [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SowUX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see from your screenshots, you put constraints on view (white view as background).

Now You need constraints on buttons and label to.
Important is that buttons doesn't have fix width constraint,... but tailing and leading constraint. 
Actually you can create similar constraints for buttons like you create constraints for view.

All of them has tailing and leading constraint to background view.

Label :

Top constraint, to background view
Fix height

Buttons :

top constraint to previous button or label 
fix height

Answer (score 0):

Check the Autolayout constraints in your nib file. Make sure that the white boxes of text that you drew out have constraints to the superview (the 'card').